# convert 12 hour time to 24 hour time in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, time

input

```
    df=pd.DataFrame({
    'name':['abc','def','ghi'],
    'time':['10:30 PM', '11:30 PM', '01:20 AM']
})
```

output

```
    name    time
0   abc     10:30 PM
1   def     11:30 PM
2   ghi     01:20 AM
```

I want to like below this which convert 12 hours to 24 hour in time column:

```
    name    time
0   abc     22:30
1   def     23:30 
2   ghi     01:20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `pd.to_datetime` to convert to datetime dtype, and cast to Python time objects via the dt accessor:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.time

# df['time'] 
# 0    22:30:00
# 1    23:30:00
# 2    01:20:00
# Name: time, dtype: object
```

...or add `strftime` to get a specific time string format:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.strftime('%H:%M')

# df['time']
# 0    22:30
# 1    23:30
# 2    01:20
# Name: time, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir... got the answer.