# Converting 12 Hour to 24 Hour time format in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a `Time` column consisting of data of type 'str' in the following format:

```
1        5:21:26 PM
2        5:21:58 PM
3        5:22:22 PM
4        5:22:36 PM
5        7:18:16 PM
```

I'm trying to convert it into a 24 Hour format that'll look like this:

```
1        17:21:26
2        17:21:58
3        17:22:22
4        17:22:36
5        19:18:16
```

I followed the solution presented in a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63968442/convert-12-hour-time-to-24-hour-time-in-pandas-dataframe) using the code

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Which throws up a frustrating error  `OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 19:30:37`

I've also found that no observation exists for `7:30:37 PM` or `19:30:37` in my data frame. The above method works well for the rest of the data as opposed to one particular observation.

Are there any ways to override this error or any alternatives to convert the data in the column?

Please Advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use format parameter with `%I:%M:%S %p` - here `%I` is for hours in `12H` format and `%p` for match `AM` or `PM`:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%I:%M:%S %p').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print (df)
       Time
1  17:21:26
2  17:21:58
3  17:22:22
4  17:22:36
5  19:18:16
```