# Turning hours, minutes and seconds (HH:MM:SS AM/PM) into 24h time in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

So, i have the following dataframe in pandas

```
+----------------+-------+-----------+----------+-------------+
|  id            |  hour |  minute   |  second  |  period     |
+----------------+-------+-----------+----------+-------------+
|  0001          |  12   |  10       |  36      |  PM         |
|  0002          |  06   |  54       |  59      |  AM         |
|  0003          |  07   |  22       |  19      |  AM         |
|  0004          |  04   |  19       |  11      |  AM         |
|  0005          |  10   |  36       |  33      |  AM         |
|  0006          |  06   |  47       |  18      |  PM         |
|  0007          |  11   |  49       |  35      |  PM         |
|  0008          |  12   |  33       |  45      |  PM         |
+----------------+-------+-----------+----------+-------------+
```

hour, minute and second are integers. I need to create a new column with the time using the 24h pattern, so I have to check the period and, if it is pm, i have to add 12 to the hour (unless it's 12, because in this case it'd be 00). Can you guys help me with this? I have no idea where to start.

The final result should look like this:

```
+----------------+-------+-----------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|  id            |  hour |  minute   |  second  |  period     | hours24     |
+----------------+-------+-----------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|  0001          |  12   |  10       |  36      |  PM         | 00:10:36    |
|  0002          |  06   |  54       |  59      |  AM         | 06:54:59    |
|  0003          |  07   |  22       |  19      |  AM         | 07:22:19    |
|  0004          |  04   |  19       |  11      |  AM         | 04:19:11    |
|  0005          |  10   |  36       |  33      |  AM         | 10:36:33    |
|  0006          |  06   |  47       |  18      |  PM         | 18:47:18    |
|  0007          |  11   |  49       |  35      |  PM         | 23:49:35    |
|  0008          |  12   |  33       |  45      |  PM         | 00:33:45    |
+----------------+-------+-----------+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: This answer my question. I just need to concatenate everything
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65340674/converting-12-hour-to-24-hour-time-format-in-pandas

Comment: How "12:10:36 PM" can give "00:10:36"?

Comment: 12 PM is midnight, so it becomes 00

Comment: 12 AM is midnight

Comment: And 12 PM is noon

Comment: Not everywhere. Please check here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock#:~:text=The%20American%20Heritage%20Dictionary%20of,12%20noon%20and%2012%20midnight.%22

Comment: @MarcosDias. Can you check `df['hours24'] = df.assign(hour=np.where(df['period'] == 'PM', df['hour'] * 2 % 24, df['hour']))[['hour', 'minute', 'second']].apply(lambda x: f"{x['hour']:02}:{x['minute']:02}:{x['second']:02}", axis=1)` please?